# GAE - When adding two floats whose sum is over 1000, the sum is changed to the thousands value

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

**This was an administrative issue. It was claimed that it was our fault, and our code was broken, when the issue was elsewhere in different code that can update what ours imports. So, this is a non-problem.**

---

We are adding to values together that are in a dictionary and storing them in a variable to then be added to the NDB datastore.

Essentially, we are importing a csv and parsing the data. If the sum of two of the values is greater than 1,000.00, the float is changed to the thousands value.

**Examples:**

- 1263.13 would change to 1
- 51367.42 would change to 51
- 218.12 would be unchanged (218.12)

We think it is an issue with storing the data, but we are having trouble reproducing the the issue, and have verified that with a small amount of data, there will be "false positives". IE: there not being an issue.

Reading csv from blob:

```
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_info.key())
raw_blob = blob_reader.read()
result = [row for row in csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(raw_blob), delimiter=',')]

# loop through all rows in the data/csv
for v, row in enumerate(result):

    if set_data_type(row, v) == False:
        return False
    else:
        length = len(result) + 1
        # check values for type
        if check_values(row, v, length) == False:
            return False
        else:
            # calculate numerical data for storage
            calculate_vars(row, v)

            if not error_log:
                # if no errors, store the row in the datastore
                store_data(row, v)

# if there are no errors, add to transaction log.
if not error_log:
    added_records = len(result)
    old_new = "Upload Success - " + str(added_records) + " records added."
    transactions(module, 'Datastore', data[0], 'CSV Bulk Upload', old_new, old_new)
```

Calculating values:

```
def calculate_vars(row, v):
    # calcuate values for storage based on
    # data passed from the csv
    try:
        float_sum = float(row['float1']) + float(row['float2'])
    except Exception, e:
        catch_error(["Value calculation error in row ", v+1, " Error: ", e])
        return False
    else:
        # global var
        calculated_val = float_sum
```

Storing Value:

```
def store_data(row, v):
    try:
        entry = Datastore(
            float_sum = calculated_val
        )
    except Exception, e:
        catch_error(["StoreDataError in row ", v, e])
        return False
    else:
        # add entry to datastore.
        entry.put()
```

The Datastore column 'float_sum' is an ndb.FloatProperty()

What we're trying to figure out is: what could cause the floats to be truncated to the thousands digits and nothing else when the number is larger than 1,000. Obviously, we are aware that adding two floats together will not cause this normally, which is why we think it could be an issue with the datastore itself.

Comment: If the input data from the CSV with numbers in the thousands contains a "," that could be your issue. The coma may need to be ommited or replaced in the float.

Try stripping the "," with replace() should they be present

Comment: The "," will also break the CSV file if present. 1,512.15 would enter the system as a "1".

Comment: This was an administrative issue. It was claimed that it was our fault, and our code was broken, when the issue was elsewhere in difference code that can update what ours imports.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is not actually an issue here, as noted in the update. This question would not be helpful, and should be closed. (I'm voting to close my own question, FYI.)